# Filter Data frame not working

Tags: python, pandas

I am filtering a data frame based on a few fields and one of them is year. The year is a float 64 data type. I am filtering where year >=2018 and engaged = Y and Tier=High or Medium

```
df = df [(df ['yearLine End Date Year']>=2018) & (df ['Engaged']=='Y') & (df ['Tiering']=='High')|(df ['Tiering']=='Medium')];
```

The other filters are working except for year and it is stil giving me back 2015, 2016 and 2017. What am i doing wrong?

Adrian

Comment: What type is your date column?

Answer (score 2):

you have mixed up and's and or's in your filter.

Try this:

```
df[(df['yearLine End Date Year']>=2018) & (df['Engaged']=='Y') & df['Tiering'].isin(['High','Medium'])]
```

or

```
df[(df['yearLine End Date Year']>=2018) & (df['Engaged']=='Y') & ((df['Tiering']=='High')|(df['Tiering']=='Medium'))]
```

PS pay attention at additional brackets at the end...